# lateinit property has not been initialized при использовании Dagger

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger2

столкнулся со следующей проблемой. У меня в классе фрагмента создавался объект презентера: `private val presenter = FavoritesPresenter()`

Я решил заменить это внедрением зависимости через Dagger 2. Делаю это следующим образом:

1)    `@Inject
    lateinit var presenter:FavoritesPresenter //Создаю переменную, куда даггер внедрит презентер`

2)

```
class FavoritesModule {

    @Inject
    fun favoritesPresenter(): FavoritesPresenter {
        return FavoritesPresenter() //Создаю модуль, который будет создавать презентер
    }

}
```

3)

```
@Component(
        modules = [FavoritesModule::class] //Создаю компонент, который собирает все модули
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<TraktTvApp> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: TraktTvApp): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent

    }

    override fun inject(application: TraktTvApp)

}
```

4) В классе активности, которая будет содержать этот фрагмент добавляю:

```
    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>
```

5) В классе Application создаю компонент:

```
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
```

Однако при запуске получаю следующую ошибку:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
>   presenter has not been initialized
>           at com.mikhailovskii.trakttv.ui.favorites.FavoritesFragment.onViewCreated(FavoritesFragment.kt:48)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

В чем проблема и как с ней справиться?

Answer (score 1):

Все модули должны быть помечены аннотацией `@Module`.

А методы, в которых создаются экземпляры классов, которые они предоставляют, должны быть помечены аннотацией `@Provides`.

`@Inject` аннотаций в модуле быть не должно.